# Compile error due boost spirit placeholder limit not more than 10

Tags: boost-spirit

I'm getting a

> "qi::_10 is not a member of qi "

error when compiling grammar for qi.

Is there a way to increase the maximum allowed?

Comment: Passing large numbers of arguments is a code smell even without template expressions. I'd say it stinks in this context. Can you give us a small example that would require this? We might be able to suggest a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off-hand: *Avoid the code smell of large numbers of function arguments*.

That said,

Before:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed03b8fd369a9fe0)</kbd>**

```
#define SPIRIT_ARGUMENTS_LIMIT 10
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

int main() {
    auto& _10 = boost::spirit::labels::_10;
}
```

After:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be8fc82ad1ded2a1)</kbd>**

```
#define SPIRIT_ARGUMENTS_LIMIT 11
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

int main() {
    auto& _10 = boost::spirit::labels::_10;
}
```

## BONUS

You can cheat and hard-code your own placeholders:

```
boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::argument<998> > const _999;
```

Note the discrepancy between `998` and `_999`; this is an implementation detail that is not documented, so it's probably better not rely on it, or at least have tests.